# Can't add new module position in vertex joomla framework

Tags: php, css, joomla, frameworks, position

I am trying to add new module position at right side of menu in joomla 3 S5 vertex framework.I have done this.In index.php added

```
       <div id = "s5_newmodule">
       <?php s5_module_call('s5_newmodule ' . ' notitle'): ?> </div>
```

in template.css

```
       #s5_newmodule {
       position:absolute;
       margin-left:50%;   
         }
```

in templatedetails.xml

```
       <position>s5_newmodule</position>
```

everything is working fine in admin panel.I can find module and add new module.I have published module and select it on all pages.But when i open it shows nothing.When opening by ?tp=1 it shows me module position but not shows it's content.My site is [eweb.on.kg](http://www.eweb.on.kg)

Comment: This question is about Joomla templates, you may get a better result if you, try asking on [the Joomla Q&A StackExhange site](http://joomla.stackexchange.com)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have wrong spacings and dots.Here is the right code.

```
  <div id="s5_newmodule">
  <?php s5_module_call('s5_newmodule','notitle'); ?> </div>
```

now it's working fine.